# How to redirect from the Django login page to a single page application?

Tags: django, redirect, authentication, single-page-application

I am building a SPA React application that is served by a single Django view at /. I am using Django's admin page for login.

If an unlogged in user navigates to /#/accounts/ the Django admin page will correctly them redirect to http://localhost:8000/admin/login/?next=/#/accounts/pp01/  for login. Once they log in, they get redirected to my Django view that is configured at the / url path.

The #/account/pp01 part of the redirect gets lost and the user gets redirected to the wrong part of my single page application (http://localhost:8000/#/). Does anyone know how to get this to work?

I don't understand why Django is cutting off the # part of the URL. Any insight would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to encode the redirect path. As it is, your browser is thinking that it should go to '#/accounts/pp01/' on the path '/admin/login?next=/', rather than the hash being part of the redirect path itself.

You can use `urllib.request.quote` to quote the path.

Comment: How would I hook into Django's redirect implementation to encode the path though?